# DBMS LOB.SUBSTR Throwing ORA-00904: Invalid Identifier Error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ora-00904

One of our cutomer is running the scripts in oracle sql developer to upgrade his database table structure, procudere & triggers etc. But while running the script, he is getting `ORA-00904: Invalid Identifier Error for DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR()` and `DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH()` in one procedure.

Can somebody tell why is happening so?

There are using Oracle Sql developer Version 3.1.07 Build MAIN-07.42 with Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine 3 possible reasons:

1. the user lacks execute privilege on sys.dbms_lob (although the
   privilege is granted to PUBLIC by default)
2. there is no synonym dbms_lob for sys.dbms_lob in the database (although such public  synonym should exist)
3. the schema, on which the customer works, contains some other package with the same name DBMS_LOB

Comment: As I am new to oracle...can you please tell me either with the help of some query or some other way, how to see whether the current oracle user has the execute privilege on DBMS_LOB or not.

Answer (score 0):

Run this sql with sys to check whether your schema has privilege to execute DBMS_LOB.

```
select * from dba_tab_privs where table_name='DBMS_LOB';
```

By default, you should see PUBLIC in the grantees.

If not, you can run sql with sys.

```
grant execute on sys.DBMS_LOB to public;
```

or

```
grant execute on sys.DBMS_LOB to <your_schema_name>
```