# Compare two CLOB columns in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I am trying to compare two columns of CLOB datatype in Oracle SQL Developer. Below is the query used,

```
select *
from t1
  join t2 on t1.reference_no = t2.reference_no
where dbms_lob.compare (t1.text, t2.t_col_clob) = 0;
```

Getting error message as

> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier.

This means I don't have access to dbms_lob.compare
How comparison can be done with using dbms_lob.compare?

Please note raised this as separate because all the information available is using dbms_lob.compare, Found nothing how this can be done without using dbms_lob.compare and also I won't be getting access to dbms_lob.compare. Please suggest a SQL way to compare this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DBMS LOB.SUBSTR Throwing ORA-00904: Invalid Identifier Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118994/dbms-lob-substr-throwing-ora-00904-invalid-identifier-error)

Comment: Sorry Kaushik, but I cant do any of the actions mentioned in that post. Is there a way to write a SQL for comparison?